# Rails raises an exception for missing translation variable at validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this translation:

```
contract: "I agree with terms and conditions of the <a href='%{contract_link}' target='_blank'>funding agreement</a> and the <a href='%{mandate_link}' target='_blank'>lawyer's mandate</a>"
```

When calling `user.valid?`, it raises `missing interpolation argument :contract_link` exception even though I've defined a message error in my model.

```
validates_acceptance_of :contract,
  on: :create,
  allow_nil: false,
  message: :contract_not_accepted,
  if: :user_has_to_accept_contract?
```

If I temporarily remove the variable, everything works fine.

Any idea how I can fix this behavior?

Comment: Where do you expect the `contract_link` value to come from?

Comment: Or do you expect it to not be used, because you set the `message` option to something else?  So they’re not related?

Comment: I don't expect it to be used, indeed. And if I remove the variable, it is actually not used. But at some point, it is parsed.